# How to assign the vaue of a JSlider to that of a variable

Tags: java, jslider

I have a slider inside another class and I want to assign the values that it has to that of a variable every time the value of the slider changes. I have this code

```
public double setSliderValue() {
    double myVariable;
    sliders.mySlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
             myVariable = Sliders.variableSlider.getValue();
            System.out.println(myVariable); //returns 0 each time
        }
    });
    return myVariable;
}
```

what have I missed / what do I need to add so that the value currently on my slider is assigned to myVariable?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but you can give the class that contains the JSlider a reference to the outer class.

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.System;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
```

The class that contains the JSlider, as an example:

```
class Window extends JFrame {
    private JSlider slider;
    // a reference to the other class needs to be final
    private final Test testClass;
    public Window(Test incomingReference) {
        // set the reference
        this.testClass = incomingReference;
        // JSlider stuff
        slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 1);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                JSlider src = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                if (src.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
                testClass.setSomeVariable(src.getValue());
                System.out.println(testClass.getSomeVariable());
            }
        });
        // window stuff
        JFrame window = new JFrame("JSlider Test");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.add(slider);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The "outer class":

```
public class Test extends Object {
    public int someVariable = 0;
    public void setSomeVariable(int value) { someVariable = value; }
    public int getSomeVariable() { return someVariable; }
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        // give the window a reference to this object
        Test foo = new Test();
        Window window = new Window(foo);
    }
}
```

Also notice the line in the `ChangeListener`: `if (!src.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;` which is not in your snippet. That prevents the `ChangeListener` from setting the value when the slider is motion.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some get and set methods to my code now. However I have done a println for my getVariable method inside my change listener and nothing is being printed. I dont think it is even registering that my slider value is being changed. Would it be something to do with how my methods are set out(hierarchy). It produces nothing when I adjust my slider for some reason

Comment: You could add more code to your question post. That way everyone can see what you have.

Comment: I have sorted everything out so that my get and set methods both return println the same value that is on my slider. I have tried putting this value into another function but it just returns 0 for the value of my variable. My code looks like                                 public double theVariable() { System.out.println(myVariable);}        I print the myvariable in my get / set methods and it gives me the value on the slider but I do it in this function and I just get 0. Why?